# Better way to calculate difference between numpy unsigned ints in Python

Tags: python, numpy, uint

I am calculating the absolute difference between two `numpy.uint8`s in python with
`d = abs(a - b)`, which results in an overflow error if `b` is bigger than `a`. What's the best way to avoid this?

Comment: Er... no it doesn't. Python automatically promotes integers to longs when necessary. Also, there's no unsigned integer type in Python. Please post code that demonstrates the problem you're actually having, and a traceback.

Comment: I get a and b from an external library (pygtk) and their type is numpy.uint8. The error is RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars. Because of this it's not possible to give a short working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your comment indicates, they aren't `int`s; they're `numpy.uint8`s. Just convert them to `int`s:

```
>>> a, b = map(numpy.uint8, (50, 60))
>>> a - b
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars
246
>>> a, b = map(int, (a, b))
>>> a - b
-10
```

Since you are concerned about speed, here are a couple of tests (borrowing [Sven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12612233/577088)'s form, with thanks):

```
>>> %timeit abs(int(a) - int(b))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 410 ns per loop
>>> %timeit a - b if a > b else b - a
1000000 loops, best of 3: 470 ns per loop
```

So yes, it's faster, but unless we're talking about doing it hundreds of millions of times, it won't matter a bit.

Comment: Is this faster than the test Ionut suggested? Because I need to do this very often.

Comment: @blues, if you have a numpy array of them (which looks a lot like a list with duck typing) you can get *much* faster probably, but if its just single values numpy can't help you with speed...

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to manually convert your numbers to Python ints first:

```
d = abs(int(a) - int(b))
```

Python ints can't overflow (unless the memory is full).

Answer (score 0):

For me it does not throw overflow error, just results in false values if `b` is bigger than `a`. To stay in `uint8` boundaries use this function:

```
def abs_dev (a, b) :
    sub1 = a - b
    sub2 = b - a
    mask = a < b
    sub1[mask] = sub2[mask]
    return sub1
```